# Imageview not showing rounded corners

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-imageview

[image]

I am trying to make my layout like this but i am not able to make my imageview like this with rounded corners. It shows perfectly in Android studio's layout editors but in real device i am getting flat corners. I tired via XML and also with code but none working for me. Please help me to make my layout like this sample image.

My layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    android:focusable="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <ProgressBar

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/User_CoverPhoto"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_shape_only"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/User_CoverPhoto"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <ProgressBar

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/User_ProfilePictures"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />
        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/round_shape_only"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/User_ProfilePictures"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="#40000000"
            android:backgroundTint="#CC000000"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Profile Picture"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/User_ProfilePictures"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.01"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/User_ProfilePictures" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="#40000000"
            android:backgroundTint="#CC000000"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Cover Photo"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/User_CoverPhoto" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="13dp"

        android:id="@+id/Grid_Recycler">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

XML for round shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#CCCCCC"/>
    <padding android:left="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"/>


    <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: You can use this lib [RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60951786/12478830

Comment: Where is your code to set image to imageview?

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60058794/2016562)

Comment: @PankajKumar I am using Glide to load images.

Comment: Check this link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners
Hopefully to find the answer

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just use the `ShapeableImageView` in the Material Components library.
Something like:

```
  <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
      ...
      app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/roundedCornersImageView"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_image" />
```

with:

```
  <style name="roundedCornersImageView" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">xxdp</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

***Note:** it requires at least the version **`1.2.0-alpha03`**.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Glide

Just write extension function for ImageView:

1. To make **rectangle** image with rounded corners

   ```
    fun ImageView.loadImageWithCustomCorners(@DrawableRes resId: Int, radius: Int) =
        Glide.with(this)
            .load(resId)
            .transform(RoundedCorners(radius))
            .into(this)
   ```
2. To make **square** image with rounded corners

   ```
    fun ImageView.loadImageWithCustomCorners(@DrawableRes resId: Int, radius: Int) =
        Glide.with(this)
            .load(resId)
            .transform(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(radius))
            .into(this)
   ```

Using in code

```
iv_service_avatar.loadImageWithCustomCorners(R.drawable.ic_default_avatar, 15)
```

*iv_service_avatar it`s ImageView ID*

Comment: Doesn't work well. Corner rounding is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

you can put your `ImageView` to a `CardView` and use the  `app:cardCornerRadius`for set image corner

Comment: Best solution and simple one.

Answer (score 2):

You should call `setClipToOutline` to `true` when using `background` with `radius` it only calls programmatically can not set by XML

```
imageView.setClipToOutline(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

For Rounded Corner you can use following Custom Layout:

> Java  : RoundedCornerImageLayout.java

```
public class RoundedCornerImageLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private final static float CORNER_RADIUS = 10.0f;
    private float cornerRadius;

    public RoundedCornerImageLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }

    public RoundedCornerImageLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public RoundedCornerImageLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        cornerRadius = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, CORNER_RADIUS, metrics);
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }


    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int count = canvas.save();

        final Path path = new Path();
        path.addRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()), cornerRadius, cornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.INTERSECT);

        canvas.clipPath(path);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restoreToCount(count);
    }
}
```

You can change the `private final static float CORNER_RADIUS = 10.0f;` according to your requirement

> in XMl file

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RoundedImageViewActivity">
    <com.example.stackdemo.ui.RoundedCornerImageLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ocean"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    </com.example.stackdemo.ui.RoundedCornerImageLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output for above code is:

[image]

I hope this helps you

Comment: Isn't better to use custom `ImageView` than `FrameLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Use `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` in such way:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="148dp"
                    android:layout_height="148dp"
                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/some_id"
                        android:layout_width="148dp"
                        android:layout_height="148dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:radius="10dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        tools:background="#EDEDED" />
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

`card_view` will be unresolved, so in order to resolve it, add `xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to the root element.

Here's the link to docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/cardview#CardView